# Resolving connection string using Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm using Ninject for dependency injection in my ASP.NET MVC project. I've lot of repository classes and each class take the connection string parameter in the constructor.

Currently for each mapping I've to pass the connection string as well.

Ex.

```
Bind<INewsRepository>().To<NewsRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "Data Source=...");
Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<ProductsRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "Data Source=...");
```

Is it possible to bind the "connectionString" directly to the configuration value at a global level instead of specifying at each binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution would be:
Wrap the connectionstring in an object, say ConnectionStringWrapper and make an Interface IConnectionStringWrapper. Use the interface in your repositories and bind the ConnectionStringWrapper to the interface using Ninjects.

Comment: Why wrap the connectionstring in an extra interface? Why not bind the connectionstring to the class constructor of each repository? Where the advantage of binding every IConnectionStringWrapper to a repo constructor?

Comment: It is all about keeping it at one place. When you want to change the connectionstring it only has to be changed in the ConnectionStringWrapper class. The interface is useful if you have multiple ConnectionStringWrapper classes, say for test, acceptance and production. You can use Ninject to bind the right class to the interface.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I've come up with

Create extension method

```
    public static class IBindingExtensions
    {
         public static IBindingWithOrOnSyntax<T> WithConnectionString<T>(this IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> binding)
         {
             return binding.WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "Data Source=..");
         }
    }
```

And call it for every connection string argument binding

```
Bind<INewsRepository>().To<NewsRepository>().WithConnectionString();
```